# PowerPoint 2013 "PasteSpecial" won't embed Excel chart as OLE Object

Tags: vba, charts, excel-2013, powerpoint-2013

I've written a macro in PowerPoint that, as part of its process, will convert a linked chart in a PowerPoint presentation to an embedded chart by copying the source Excel chart and pasting that copied chart in as an OLE object -- the specific command is, "sldComponent.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteOLEObject)".

Until today, this has worked fine in all versions from 2003 to 2010.  However, when trying to run this function in 2013/365, I keep getting a run-time error stating "The specified data type is not available" (-2147188160 / 80048240).  I also notice that in the Microsoft Developers Reference webpage, "ppPasteOLEObject" is no longer listed as an acceptable datatype for the PasteSpecial method (when used with the Shapes collection).

I have found several ways to programmatically paste the chart as a picture, but whenever I click on the pasted chart and try to access the data, I keep getting the message "The linked file is not available."  I want the data to be entirely self-contained so the PowerPoint user can edit it without reference to the original Excel file.  Interestingly, when I stop the PowerPoint macro at the buggy line and then manually click "Paste" on the ribbon, the copied chart *does* paste, fully embedded with data accessible, into the active slide -- so the chart is getting copied into the Clipboard; the PowerPoint macro is simply unable to read and paste it for some reason.  Even more interestingly (read: frustratingly), the PasteSpecial(ppPasteOLEObject) command will work for *tables* copied from Excel, i.e. cell ranges, but *not* for charts.

What happened?  How does one use VBA code in PowerPoint 2013 to embed (i.e. insert a previously-created, self-contained Excel chart including all data right in the presentation slide) an Excel chart in the new version?

ADD:  I should also note that the command used to get the chart from the source worksheet in Excel is "xlCopySheet.ChartObjects(1).Select", then "appExcel.Selection.Copy".  Is the problem that the chosen Copy syntax is not capturing the entire chart including data but only the display?  What is the correct Copy syntax to use here?

ADD 2:  Further specification: The original macro was saved and was running with both Excel and PowerPoint in Compatibility (97-2003) mode, although the apps themselves are the 2013/Office 365 versions.

Comment: "If I copy the chart in Excel and use this in the PowerPoint VB Immediate Window...."  What is the "Immediate Window"?  Is it different from the normal VB editor screen activated by ALT + F11?

Answer (score 2):

If you paste the chart as a "Microsoft Office Graphic Object", the chart is pasted as an Excel chart. You can format it within PowerPoint using the Excel ribbon's Chart Tools tab, which appear in PowerPoint. If you click any of the edit/select data buttons, it opens the data in Excel.

If you paste the chart as a Microsoft Excel Chart Object, it is pasted as an embedded workbook (the entire workbook, not just the chart and its data), with a new chart sheet inserted in the embedded workbook, and this chart sheet is what is visible. You need to double click to format or edit the chart, which opens the embedded workbook in Excel, and may mess up the size of the embedded object (so it's chart-sheet sized, not chart-embedded-in-the-worksheet sized) and things like font size.

If I copy the chart in Excel and use this in the PowerPoint VB Immediate Window

```
activepresentation.Slides(3).Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteOLEObject
```

I get the second behavior.

You might want to try copying the chart using this:

```
xlCopySheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.Copy
```

Comment: Because of the screwiness with Excel charts within PowerPoint, I'm working on a routine that will not exactly copy the Excel chart, but instead create a chart in PowerPoint with or without the same formats, and find the Excel data used in the Excel chart, and paste it into the PowerPoint DataSheet with or without links to the original Excel data.

Comment: Your first option sounds promising; I don't need to paste the entire source workbook, just to make the data itself accessible somehow.  What datatype would you use with "PasteSpecial" in VBA to paste a chart as a Microsoft Office Graphic Object?

Comment: BTW, using the "ChartObjects(1).Chart.Copy" syntax fails; I get the error message "Copy method of Chart Class failed".

Comment: Try ChartObjects(1).Chart.ChartArea.Copy

Comment: If you use "ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Paste", you get the MSO Graphic Object, since that's the default format for a pasted chart. Note that the data remains in the original Excel file, which I think was part of your initial statement.